# for loop not executing/running correctly

Tags: c#, for-loop

Here's the code can anyone help?

```
using System;
namespace Mathhero
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Random numgen = new Random();
                int num1 = numgen.Next(1, 11);
                int num2 = numgen.Next(1, 11);
                Console.WriteLine("What is " + num1 + " * " + num2 + " equal to ???");
                int Answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (Answer == num1 * num2)
                {
                    int ran = numgen.Next(1, 4);
                    switch (ran)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("Good work!!");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine("Nice!!!");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Excellent!!");
                            break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    int ran = numgen.Next(1, 4);
                    switch (ran)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!!");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine("Try hard!!!");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("DO homework!!");
                            break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                i=i+ 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Test Ended!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

The for loop is exiting after 6 questions while it should after 10.

Comment: You do not need to do ```i = i + 1``` at the end of your loop, it is actually doing that by default when you declare your loop => ```for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)```, the i++ will increment your variable automatically when the code reaches the end of the loop.

Comment: In existence of excellent answers just a debugging hint: If you encounter a for loop that ends "early" (or late for that matter) use an output or a breakpoint to check the index variable. Is it changing its value as expected in each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

You are increasing your index within the for loop and thus shortening it's run.

```
 else
            {
                int ran = numgen.Next(1, 4);
                switch (ran)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong!!");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Try hard!!!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("DO homework!!");
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            i=i+ 1;   //// <------- HERE
        }
```

Your for loop already takes care of incrementing the index by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop "header" increments `i` in the normal way:

```cs
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
```

However, *within* the loop you *also* increment `i`, for no apparent reason:

```cs
i=i+ 1;
```

So you're incrementing `i` twice for each iteration of the loop. That makes it reach its end point earlier.

To execute 10 times, you should have:

```cs
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

(note the use of `<` rather than `<=`) and remove the `i = i + 1;` statement entirely.

I'd also recommend the general principle of declaring each variable in as small a scope as you can - in this case, *in* the for loop:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

That's more idiomatic and "tidy" IMO than declaring it *before* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

the loop will run for 11 times as you are initializing i=0 and i<=10 so should check this...
Second i don't understand why are you doing i+1 at the end because loop is already incrementing so you should check this also..

Comment: _"the loop will run for 11 times"_ - no it won't. Obviously and explicitly stated by OP.

Comment: Incorrect assertion that the loop will run 11 times. It does not. You were correct to point out the that extra increment of i is not required.